# Auto close quotation mark on vscode for mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, brackets

I'm using VScode for mac and my VS dosen't work auto close on quotation mark!

All others Brackets works the auto close, but not for quotation mark! :(

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: I'm using with Javascript! But no language works :(